# Contact requirement for blue card when changing job

Tags: germany, eu, blue-card

1. I have a blue card.
2. Non-EU citizen.

I want to change my job and I have a new contract. It meets the minimum salary requirement but it's a limited time contract for 12 months. My questions are:

1. How to proceed when changing job for a blue card holder?
2. Is there any requirement for the contract to meet the blue card requirement other than the salary? For example, is it ok in my case to keep the blue card with a limited contract duration? Any other requirement like employer's contribution to social security?

Comment: @MartinBonner in French it's bleu, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [BAMF](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Infothek/FragenAntworten/BlaueKarteEU/blaue-karte-eu-node.html):

- If you have held the blue card for two years, you can just change job (provided it is highly skilled - if it is in the same field and meets the salary requirement, it probably is).
- If you haven't held the blue card for two years:

  > Any change of job during the first two years of employment requires
  >   the approval of the immigration authority (section 19a subs. 4 of the
  >   German Residence Act). Approval is subject to the same preconditions
  >   as initial issuance.
- There is no requirement I can see that the job offer has to be for permanent employment rather than a time limited contract.
- If you come to the end of your contract without another one, you have to tell the immigration authority.

  > Persons who are resident are obliged to notify the competent
  >   immigration authority of the loss of their job where employment is
  >   subject to approval by the immigration authority. The foreigner in
  >   question initially still holds a valid residence title, but the
  >   immigration authority may stipulate a subsequent time limitation at
  >   its discretion.

There is more useful information [here](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Migration/Arbeiten/BuergerDrittstaat/BlaueKarte/blaue-karte-node.html)