# Blue Card Germany

Tags: germany, resident-permit, blue-card

I have a Blue Card in Germany. I am working now but i just wanted to know, if for some reason company does not want me after 6 months. Does anybody knows what will happen ?!
In my contract says that i have 6 months as a probation period. I am worried what will happen to me if company decides that after 6 months they don’t want me. 
Thanks.

Comment: Related question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/14504/contact-requirement-for-blue-card-when-changing-job?r=SearchResults

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing jobs after 6 months as a Blue Card holder](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12356/changing-jobs-after-6-months-as-a-blue-card-holder)